# Вывод всех городов по области GOOGLE MAPS API

Tags: google-maps-api, карты

Нужен запрос, который будет выводить все города, которые находятся к примеру в Houston.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Houston

Comment: Запрос куда/во что?

Comment: браузерный запрос, как указан в вопросе самом, может какие-то параметры есть для этого.

Comment: Ты же сам привёл пример запроса для браузера, который выдаёт список городов в JSON формате.

Comment: Он мне выдал информацию о городе. А мне нужны города, которые находятся в его области.

Comment: По ссылке ниже говорят что сервис Google Maps такого не предоставляет.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686309/list-of-surrounding-towns-within-a-given-radius

Comment: А есть какие-нибудь сервисы, которые смогут это сделать? Может API или готовые базы?

Базы находил, но увы, нет связей, не реально определить, в какой области город.

Comment: @MAKADORE [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) можно выгрузить и установить локально. И предвидя ваш возможный ответ, что там нет связей, отвечу заранее: Они там есть, возможно, не так очевидны как хочется, но есть.